# Array iterate and pop()

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm looking for a simple method to iterate over an array and generate a result like below... Better if someone can show me how to do this in the ES2015 way.

```
var numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

/* Expected result */

/* 
  0: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
  1: ['one', 'two'],
  2: ['one']
*/
```

https://jsfiddle.net/minuwan/1eL83sbz

Comment: You're gonna wanna clone the array for each loop, `var clone = myArray.slice(0);`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vp0f2woq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the sliced array.

```js
var numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    result = numbers.map(function (_, i, a) {
        return a.slice(0, a.length - i);
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use slice to get the output you want instead of using `pop` since it will modify your `numbers` array

```js
    var numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    var array = [];
    var arrayLength = numbers.length;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      array[i] =  numbers.slice(0, arrayLength - i);
    }
    
    console.log(array);
```

or  you would simply use map with slice

```js
var numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three']
var array = numbers.map(function (_, i) {
    return numbers.slice(0, numbers.length - i);
});

console.log(array);
```